# Checking to see if multiple values in a line in a 2d array are the same

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array list, its size depends on two variables specified by the user upon startup, and is then filled with zeros. As the program progresses some of the grid will be filled with ones, some with twos. Thats all pretty simple, what I have no idea how to do is to check if there are any lines of zeros in my array, either horizontal or vertical. Anyone know how?

Just an edit here, thanks for all the advice, all of the answers are great solutions, however I miss worded my question, I need to check for lines of zeros, anywhere from 2 long to whatever the user sets the size of the array to.

Comment: Show us some of your relevant code and someone will definitely be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to create a for loop to loop through the row and then within that another for loop (don't forget to use a different variable) to loop through the column

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any utility class that solve this problem, but you can create one easily using the method [Arrays.deepEquals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[])).

Create an array of zeros and compare it with each row and file in your matrix to obtain which of them are zero-value arrays

Answer (score 0):

One idea I have is to create two 1D arrays, one with the length and the other with the height of your 2D array and fill them with zeros. Then with two simple for-loops you can read all the values in your 2D array. For each row if you find a value that is different from 0 you will set that position in the corresponding array to one. I guess it would be simpler to just write some code and show you:

```
int x = 10, y = 5; // numbers just for the example
int values[][] = new int[x][y];
int foo1[] = new int[x];
int foo2[] = new int[y];

for(int i=0 ; i<x ; i++)
    for(int j=0 ; i<y ; j++)
        if(values[i][j] != 0) {
            foo1[i] = 1;
            foo2[j] = 1;
        }
```

Once you have done this you can loop through foo1[] and foo2[] and if you find any zeros you will know that at that corresponding row or column there is a row or column of zeros in values[][]

Comment: Remember to fill foo1[] and foo2[] with zeros at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

One possible way could be to mark columns and rows as you process them as being not all 0s. Here's the idea in Pseudo-code

notAll0sC = Array[numberOfColumns] initiated to 0

notAll0sR = Array[numberOfRows] initiated to 0

Now during your processing you will have something like

myTwoDimArray[R][C] = 1

notAll0sC[C] = 1

notAll0sR[R] = 1

Then at the end you can loop through the notAll0sC and notAll0sR to find out which ones are still 0s and as such those would be the rows and columns that are all 0s.

Answer (score 0):

I've understood your question hopefully. This might help..

```
int m,n;    
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
       m=0;
       for(int j=0;j<a[0].length;j++){
           if(a[i][j]==0)
                 m++;
           else break;
       }
       if(m==a[0].length)
           // if true? There's a row of zeros
}

for(int u=0;u<a[0].length;u++){
       n=0;
       for(int v=0;v<a.length;v++){
           if(a[v][u]==0)
                 n++;
           else break;
       }
       if(n==a.length)
           // if true? There's a columns of zeros
}
```